# The basic primitive recursive functions

Tags: functions, function-construction, pattern-matching, symbolic, functional-style

How can the [basic primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition) be expressed in the Wolfram Language?

Apparently [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40812/defining-a-formal-primitive-recursion)'s an example for primitive recursion:

```
prRec[f_, g_] :=If[#1 === 0, f[##2], g[#1 - 1, #0[#1 - 1, ##2], ##2]] &
```

The basic primitive recursive functions are:

- Zero function $0$
- Successor function $S(k) = k + 1$
- Projection function $\pi_i(x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots)=x_i$
- Composition
- Primitive recursion

Comment: Could you expand the question a bit? Specifically, state how the included example fails to answer the question, and how the question is different from the one you linked.

Comment: @SimonWoods That one was specifically for the primitive recursion operator.

Comment: When early H. Sapiens painted pictures of themselves painting on cave walls, was that primitive recursion?

Comment: Related: [(1532)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/can-someone-explain-this-snippet)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau [The coats of arms of Russia](http://en.zlatoust.com/upload/iblock/3c8/3c86c3ebcf0c61fb48c58c786e35dbd8.jpg). Take a close look at the sceptre on the claw at the left

Comment: Given the nature of this, I'm not entirely sure what you need, because I'm not familiar with the ideas. Do the basic primitive recursive functions need to be recursive *themselves*, or is it just that any function can be built recursively *from* these functions, and these basic functions can be non-recursive? For instance, would `succ[k_] := k+1` be okay, or does it need to be `succ := If[#1 == 0, 1, #0[#1 - 1] + 1] &`, i.e. a version that calls itself?

Comment: @march It's that any primitive recursive function can be built from these functions. For the successor function, the first example would be fine.

Comment: Steven W. takes crack at defining primitive recursive functions in M here:http://www.wolframscience.com/nks/notes-4-3--primitive-recursive-functions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of these could be implemented differently, of course, but I've gone the way of making all of them pure functions (in the *Mathematica* sense). Every single one takes a `Sequence` of arguments as the inputs, but some of them accept *function* names as inputs first, and the projection function accepts an *integer* for which argument is chosen (I have chosen to use *Mathematica* indexing which starts at one).

- Zero function

  ```
  zero = 0 &;
  zero[5]
  (* 0 *)
  ```
- Successor function

  ```
  succ = # + 1 &;
  succ /@ Range[10]
  (* {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11} *)
  ```
- Projection function

  ```
  proj[n_Integer] = {##}[[n]] &;
  proj[3][a, b, c, d]
  (* c *)
  ```

  or

  ```
  proj[n_Integer] := Slot[n] &
  ```
- Composition

  ```
  comp[f_, gs__] = f @@ Through@{gs}@## &;
  comp[f, g1, g2, g3][a, b, c, d, e]
  (* f[g1[a, b, c, d, e], g2[a, b, c, d, e], g3[a, b, c, d, e]] *)
  ```
- Primitive Recursion: with this one, you need to be careful. It *assumes* that the first argument is a non-negative integer. If it is not, there will be an infinite recursion.

  ```
  prec[f_, g_] = If[#1 == 0, f[##2], g[#1 - 1, #0[#1 - 1, ##2], ##2]] &;
  prec[f, g][3, x, y, z]
  (* g[2, g[1, g[0, f[x, y, z], x, y, z], x, y, z], x, y, z] *)
  ```

---

Possible issue, based on my lack of knowledge about how this is implemented. The successor function seems to be what is used to decrement arguments to the function in order to define things recursively. For instance, the binary `add` function can be implemented via

```
add[0, x_] := proj[1][x]
add[n_, x_] := succ[proj[2][n - 1, add[n - 1, x], x]]
```

but it *cannot* be implemented via

```
add[0, x_] := proj[1][x]
add[succ[n_], x_] := succ[proj[2][n, add[n, x], x]]
```

which is the official definition of the primitive recursive binary sum function in terms of the basic primitive recursive functions.

Comment: How would you express the `add` function directly in terms of `prec`?

Comment: @user1667423. I don't know. Do you know how it's done "formally"? That is, if you have a link to something that shows how to do it symbolically (similar to what's done on the [Wikipedia page on primitive recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Addition), which is basically what I used to learn about this), then I can probably interpret it in terms of the *Mathematica* language. Otherwise, you should probably do some of this work yourself.

Comment: Ah, I found the answer under https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Addition. So `f` is `proj[1]` and `g` is `comp[succ, proj[2]]` in `add = prec[f, g]`. Thanks for your help with this question!